# What does a wildcard route do in express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

So, I have these routes in my **app.js** file.

```
app.use("/api/v1/users", userRouter)
app.use("/*", indexRouter)
```

And in **index.js**:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Gratitude Journal App' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

What does the * do exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will render index page for all of your app's GET request. It (*) will match any string(route) after it.